# Quarkus RestClient close()

Tags: quarkus

I would like to know what is the behavior of quarkus when a RestClient is injected through CDI.

Does it close the client automatically in the example below?

```
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@RegisterRestClient
@RegisterClientHeaders
public interface CarClient {
   @GET
   @Path("/cars/{id}")
   @Timeout(4500L)
   Car getCar(@PathParam("id") String id);
}

@Inject
@RestClient
CarClient carClient;
```

Or Quarkus requires it to extends AutoCloseable like the example below?

```
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@RegisterRestClient
@RegisterClientHeaders
public interface CarClient extends AutoCloseable {
   @GET
   @Path("/cars/{id}")
   @Timeout(4500L)
   Car getCar(@PathParam("id") String id);
}

@Inject
@RestClient
CarClient carClient;
```

We are getting some warnings and we need to be sure if everything is being closed.

```
WARN: RESTEASY004687: Closing a class org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient43Engine instance for you. Please close clients yourself.
```

PS: Suggestion for the quarkus team to show in the warning the client with the issue :)

Comment: Do you inject the client in a RequestScoped bean? I suspect you did not define a scope for your rest clients and they are therefore ´Dependent´, so afaik the same scope as the target class. We use `Singleton` for our clients and I have never seen the exception.

Answer (score 6):

Quarkus team said it was required to extends AutoCloseable in RestClient interfaces so connection is closed automatically.

Comment: It's a good assumption, but they still might have a bug in the framework. 1. Has the adding of the Autoclosable removed the warning? 2. Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: user4081947 could you provide a source for this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per source this engine is a ManualClosing one, see https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/main/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/ApacheHttpClient43Engine.java

You should set a breakpoint here : https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/main/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/ApacheHttpClient43Engine.java#L37

The key allowClosingHttpClient is set here : https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/blob/main/resteasy-client/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/engines/ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java#L163

So if you want to be sure, and understand why this warning happens in your case, you should set these breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is bug. The workaround is to make the client extend Closeable(still present in Quarkus 2.16.1).